# Is there a way to use a JDBC as a input resource for Hadoop's MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have data in a PostgreSQL DB and I'd like to get it, treat it and save it to a HBase DB. Is it possible to distribute somehow the JDBC operation in a Map operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that by `DBInputFormat`:

`DBInputFormat` uses `JDBC` to connect to data sources. Because `JDBC` is widely implemented, `DBInputFormat` can work with `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, and several other database systems. Individual database vendors provide `JDBC` drivers to allow third-party applications (like `Hadoop`) to connect to their databases.

The `DBInputFormat` is an `InputFormat` class that allows you to read data from a database. An `InputFormat` is Hadoop’s formalization of a data source; it can mean files formatted in a particular way, data read from a database, etc. `DBInputFormat` provides a simple method of scanning entire tables from a database, as well as the means to read from arbitrary `SQL` queries performed against the database.

[LINK](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/)

Comment: I'm looking into postgres views. Can it be accessed via DBInputFormat.setInput(...) in map reduce jobs?Any suggestions are helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for Sqoop, which is designed to import from SQL servers to HDFS stack technologies. It puts the data it gets from a JDBC connection into HDFS, thereby splitting it across your Hadoop NameNodes. I believe this is what you are looking for.

SQl to hadOOP = SQOOP, get it?

Sqoop can import into HBase. See [this link](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase).